# Mock an iterator to throw exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, iterator, mocking

I'm, using **python 2.7.15rc1**. I'm trying to mock an iterator so that it throws exception when iterating over it.
Eg:

```
elements = [1,2,3,Exception('boom!')]
iterable = <create a mock iterable to iterate over "elements">

# this does not print anything.
for value in iterable:
   ...
```

I've tried using the `side_effect` attribute on the `next()` method of a `MagicMock` instance like so:

```
from mock import MagicMock

mocked_next = MagicMock()
mocked_next.next.side_effect = [1,2,3,Exception('boom!')]

mocked_iterable = MagicMock()
mocked_iterable.__iter__.return_value = mocked_next
...
# This does not print anything and no exception is raised
for value in mocked_iterable:
    print(value)
```

I assumed that the `for` loop would end up calling `__iter__` on the `mocked_iterable`, which returned another mock object with its `next` attribute having a `side_effect`. My expectation was that the loop would end up calling `mocked_next.next()` which would iterate the list I provided to it in the `side_effect`.

Clearly, my understanding is not correct. What am I missing here? Can this be achieved purely using mock, or do I have to create a custom iterator to implement this behavior?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to test the exception handling part of a piece of code that iterates over an iterable and hence trying to emulate an iterator throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not suitable for `MagicMock`, since `side_effect` can be either an exception or an iterable, but not both. You should instead create a class with an `__iter__` method that yields the items in the given sequence and then raises the given exception:

```
class ExceptionRaisingIterable:
    def __init__(self, seq, exception):
        self.seq = seq
        self.exception = exception

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.seq:
            yield i
        raise self.exception

for value in ExceptionRaisingIterable([1, 2, 3], Exception('boom!')):
    print(value)
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for value in ExceptionRaisingIterable([1, 2, 3], Exception('boom!')):
  File "test.py", line 9, in __iter__
    raise self.exception
Exception: boom!
```

Comment: "since side_effect can be either an exception or an iterable, but not both" - This isn't correct. From the docs: **If you pass in an iterable, it is used to retrieve an iterator which must yield a value on every call. This value can either be an exception instance to be raised, or a value to be returned from the call to the mock**.